# R Markdown opens "df" tabs?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

Every time I run a chunk in R markdown, it opens several "df" tabs with an icon that looks like glasses next to it. It happens even when I am running a chunk that does not create any data frames (e.g., a setup chunk where I load libraries). Is there a way to fix this? I am using the latest version of R and R Studio (R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21); R Studio Version 2023.06.0+421)

I tried re-installing R and R Studio, clearing the environment, quitting & re-starting the apps.

Edit:

Adding screenshot of R Markdown settings per suggestions in the comments.
[image: 1]
Also screenshot of the code chunk:
[image: 2]

I would add screenshots of the "df"s too, but it happens sporadically and it doesn't happen anymore (I've already cleared the environment). Will come back to this post and add screenshots if it happens again.

Edit2: Adding screenshots of the tab(s) [image: 3]

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code chunk? Otherwise, it is barely possible to give you an answer. Check if you have any `View()` or `view()` functions in the code chunk which might cause this.

Comment: In RStudio, if you look at Tools > Global Options > R Markdown > Basic, could you screenshot the options you have selected and add that to your question?

Comment: It might also help to see a screenshot of the "df" tabs that open.

Comment: All that said, this sounds like an RStudio interface issue, you might have better luck posting on the RStudio Community Forums.